# What data types do the RangeValidator control support?

Tags: c#, asp.net

explain the rangevalidator control,is it take string also? explain thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It supports

1. Currency
2. Date
3. Double
4. Integer
5. String

For comparing strings better to use **Regularexpressionvalidator** instead of Rangevalidator.

In case of type string for the range validator it will only check the character by character, not the length of the string.

Comment: thank u Mr. adamantium for explanation

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does support string range validation.
Please look at the documentation before asking question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx

Comment: :) When downvoting, care to explain the reason?

Comment: This doesn't deserve a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt.aspx):

> The RangeValidator control allows you to check whether a user's entry is between a specified upper and a specified lower boundary. You can check ranges within pairs of numbers, alphabetic characters, and dates. Boundaries are expressed as constants.

Comment: Thank u Mr. Marek K for explanation